# Drupal 8 JSON migration process plugin callback. Unix to date conversion

Tags: php, unix, drupal, database-migration, drupal-8

I am writing a custom migration module to move some data from a JSON feed into Drupal 8.

I have basic strings going into the content type but cant seem to convert unix time format during the process phase in the install yml file.

I have

```
process:
  field_post_date:
    -
      plugin: callback
      callable: date
      source: publish_date
```

Current 
Input - 1486573222000 
Output - 1486573222000

I would like
Input - 1486573222000
Output - 02-08-2017T17:00:22

I would like to be able to pass an argument into a custom php function if possible and I think I could get it to work. Not sure how though have look over the doc here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process/process-plugin-callback but still can seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2820490. Once that patch lands, the method will be in core, but until then you have to install that patch and use the format_date process plugin. A callback won't work, because you have to pass multiple arguments to the callback and that just isn't possible.

Comment: I believe I can do it with one argument. Can you provide and example of passing 1 argument to a php function then back to the yml markup?

Comment: Why can you not use the already provided process plugin? It will format any date string from any format into any format.

Comment: Your right was just kinda new to all this I ended up moving my code into a custom process plugin! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could not quite get this to work the way I wanted it to so I wrote a php function to format the date in the json file before running drush mi ***. It parses Date and updated when the unix is in milliseconds.

```
<!-- This is a custom php function to convert time stamps from unix to MM-DD-YYYYTHR:MM:SS which is accepted by drupal Date field type-->
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('GMT'); 
$json = file_get_contents("**your-url**.json");
$array = json_decode($json);
foreach($array->blog_posts as $item){
    echo "<br>";
    $num = $item->publish_date;
    $int = (int)$num;
    $float = (float)$num;
    $epoch = $float;
    $seconds = $epoch * .001;
    $item->publish_date = gmdate('Y-m-d',$seconds)."T".gmdate('H:i:s',$seconds);
}
foreach($array->blog_posts as $item1){
    echo $item1->updated;
    echo "<br>";
    $num = $item1->updated;
    $int = (int)$num;
    $float = (float)$num;
    $epoch = $float;
    $seconds = $epoch * .001;
    $item1->updated = $seconds;
}
file_put_contents('**export**.json', json_encode($array));
?>
```